# How does import in css work., and what does this mean

Tags: html, css

In one of my css files there is this entry

```
@import url('bootstrap.min.css');
```

What does this do, does it get it from the internet or local pc.

Comment: local PC, because that's a file name, not a full URL. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url

Comment: `@import` as the name suggest improting another file. Thatw ay you can load the content of another css file in your css file. As already said correctly, it is a relative path and as such it will only work locally.

Answer (score 1):

if you use import rule in your css file , in fact you export all things in bootstrap file in you own css file. just this.

read this article : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.asp

Answer (score 0):

Importing css means to import the file of css from inside the directory or project.
e.g. in REACTJS we don't provide the link of our css file inside our view file, we only import it. And its not only in CSS case, it also occurs in various other files like JS or image etc.